# How to remove the selection of empty space in nav

Tags: html, css

How to remove the selection of empty space in nav
i had use list style type none property.

See in the pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/abnkE.png

Comment: [Done](https://imgur.com/a/5oVBtRK)

Answer (score 1):

put the padding of li padding:0px, and margin from left and right 5px;
it should be work...!!!

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Service</li>
    <li>Info</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset default styles by using reset CSS could be helpful.
Add this line to `head`

```
<link href="https://cdnout.com/meyer-reset/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```